# AWS EC2 private instance in public subnet - Cannot run apt-get update or ping google

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a private EC2 instance in a public subnet. I am not able to run apt-get update or ping google or do anything internet facing.

I see that the security group for this instance has outbound rules set to "all traffic" to 0.0.0.0/0. Also, the route table has an entry for 0.0.0.0/0 to IGW. So, looks like it should work.

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: the route table is correctly attached to the subnet where your ec2 is located?

Comment: "private EC2 instance in a public subnet" - what does it even mean? Instance has no public IP address?

Comment: @marcin Yes. No public IP address

Comment: @fun_times Yes. It is attached

Answer (score 4):

> No public IP address

Without a public IP, an instance in a public subnet, can't connect to the internet. Public IP is required to communicate with services outside of a VPC.

If you don't want to add public IP to your instance, you have to place it in a **private subnet**, and correctly setup [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in a public subnet and route tables to it. This way your instance will connect to the internet through NAT. NAT will be your proxy which will have public IP. But your instance will not need to have it.

Comment: Well, technically the instance doesn't *have to* live in a private subnet, right? It could live in the public one. As long as the routing to the NAT gateway is configured properly the connectivity would still work

Comment: @Paolo You won't be able to setup route from your instance to NAT if its in public subnet. route tables are for subnets, not instances.

Comment: Right, so all that needs to be done is to create a new subnet, place the NAT gateway in it, and configure routing from one public subnet (with the private instance in it) to the public subnet with the NAT gateway. This is easier than destroying and creating a new instance

Comment: @Paolo Read the docs I link how to setup NAT and route tables. Nat must be in public subnet, not private.

Comment: Yes, I know. What I am saying is that all that is needed to solve OP's question is the creation of a new public subnet, and in there the NAT gateway should be created. There's no need to destroy and re-create the instance

Comment: @Paolo Yes, you can do that if you don't want to recreate the instance.

Comment: @paolo You mean assign a secondary network interface to my existing instance in the new subnet?

Comment: @Marcin So as to not recreate the instance, is this what's required? 
1. Create a new public subnet
2. Create a NAT in this subnet with an Elastic IP
3. Create a new route table with 0.0.0.0/0 for NAT
4. Associate this route table with the new subnet
5. Add a new interface for this EC2 instance in the new subnet

Comment: @mentalic - you have to turn your current public subnet into a private subnet, by removing the route to the Internet Gateway and replacing it with a route to the NAT. That may mean that other instances in your formerly-public subnet will no longer have direct Internet access. I think you'll find that it will be _much_ less work to just recreate the instance.